# The lighttpd+Python equivalent of Apache+PHP+FastCGI+suEXEC (or: lighttpd FastCGI-executing Python scripts with the permission of the owner)

Tags: python, lighttpd, fastcgi

It's been years since I last had anything to do with web servers. The last time, I found that Apache along with FastCGI (actually mod_fcgid) and suEXEC gave me a seemingly perfect way to handle PHP; each script would run with the privileges of its owner thanks to suEXEC, and FastCGI would make it so that PHP didn't need to spawn every time a request came in. Absolutely marvellous!

Now I'm setting up a little VPS just for fun. Due to memory constraints (and the desire to learn something new), Apache has been replaced by lighttpd. Moreover, the last time around I swore never to touch PHP again. So this time, I'll use Python (and possibly Haskell) for my dynamic needs. I've played around a bit with lighttpd+FastCGI+Python, but I can't see how I should tie this in with something equivalent to suEXEC.

So, to the question: Could someone give me some pointers as to how I would go about setting up lighttpd with FastCGI in such a way that every Python script requested is run (through FastCGI) with the privileges of the user owning said script?

Answer (score 1):

In Apache you can define patterns (similar to mod_cgi) which designate requests sent to FastCGI applications.  Mod_fcgid is a FastCGI process manager, spawning each unique application with a specific permissions (suexec).

This is *not* possible with lighttpd.  Lighttpd does not have a FastCGI process manager, which can change permissions, built-in (which is what mod_fcgid does).

The closest you will get with lighttpd is [spawn-fcgi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi/wiki), which coincidentally comes from the lighttpd project.  Take a look at the lighttpd [ModFastCGI](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs%3AModFastCGI) wiki under External Spawning.